# starting with google app engine on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to write my first google app engine sample, with django.

I followed:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python

and then:
https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.115566598.1847531954.1430589011

but I was unable to run it:

when I'm trying to run the sample locally (python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000)
I'm getting: ImportError: No module named google3.storage.onestore.v3

any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Posting code here might help. Links for reference are OK, but we'd like to see everything relevant here, as linked pages might be changed some time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to run the Django development server, not the App Engine development server. You need to be running the latter so that import paths can be adjusted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the problem was with path of the google_appengine.
I solved it by adding:
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/me/google_projects/google_appengine')

what helped me was: http://askubuntu.com/questions/123553/how-to-install-google-appengine
cd ~
mkdir google_projects
cd google_projects
wget -O gae.zip  https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.20.zip
unzip gae.zip
rm gae.zip
cp -r google_appengine/new_project_template testapp
python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py testapp